# React Native Axios get filtered by key of array

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, axios

I have an array of objects like this:

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 14,
        "banner_type_id": 1,
        "name": "banner2022",
    },
    {
        "id": 12,
        "banner_type_id": 1,
        "name": "banner845",
    },
    {
        "id": 8,
        "banner_type_id": 4,
        "name": "banner_powertools"
    },
]
```

And these the code:

```
    useEffect(() => {
        getData();
    }, []);

    const getData = () => {
        Axios.get(baseUrl)
            .then(res => {
                console.log('theres: ', res.data.data);
                setBanner(res.data.data);

            })
    }
```

This result succeed get all-data. But, I just want display the data that only  have banner_type_id ==4. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are looking just to display the element with `banner_type_id === 4`, try using `array.filter()`.

For example, you could create a separate function like `const filtered = banner.filter((x) => x.banner_type_id === 4)`. Then in your return statement you could map over that function like so `{filtered.map(x => {return <h1>{x.banner_type_id}</h1>})`. You could check this [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/goofy-architecture-wqyws5?file=/src/App.js) that I created.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript '[find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)' method to get the data with particular id.

```
const getData = () => {
    Axios.get(baseUrl)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('theres: ', res.data.data);

            const banner = res.data.data.find(d => d.banner_type_id === 4)

            if (banner) {
                setBanner(banner.name);
            }
        })
}
```